# Python packaging: What to do with auxiliary modules that I use in most of my projects

Tags: python, publish, pypi

I have a number of auxiliary modules that I use throughout my different projects. For example, these auxiliary modules contain some code for logging, files, decorators, etc.

For my personal use, I can simply bundle and install all auxiliary modules.

If I want to publish my projects on PyPI, however, what is the most appropriate way to go? Is it appropriate to also publish the auxiliary modules as a package -- even though they hardly make sense to bundle and are hardly useful for anyone to install except when they use my other projects -- and then require the installation of that auxiliary package for each of my other projects?

Comment: Unless they're large, it's probably easier to just bundle them as part of your main projects. Sure, if people install more than one of your projects they might have a handful of redundant files, but that's probably kilobytes at most.

Comment: @Amber Sorry for a maybe stupid question, I'm new to packaging, but how do I bundle them into my main projects without copying files around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uncommon to split libraries like these into separate "project"/package, for example [krux/tcp-stream-kafka-producer](https://github.com/krux/tcp-stream-kafka-producer) is based on [krux/java-stdlib](https://github.com/krux/java-stdlib) (random example - just because I was browsing the repos yesterday...)

So, I would suggest you name the utilities as `<something>-util` (or "various", or "stuff" :)) and release them separately as a module on pipy. This is the cleaner way to do this since it allows different projects to use different versions of the underlying lib without having to maintain multiple copies of that library and with clear versioning/dependencies.

Your other options:

1. Include the library in the most popular project: This leads to project dependencies that do not really make sense. For example, if that project changes major version, are the dependent projects affected? (you cannot know)
2. Copy in every project you use: This might be OK for a short time and a few projects, however, soon you will loose track of changes and the common files will get out of sync. I have done that before and it is very annoying spending a few hours to debug something that you have already patched in another project!

The only downside I see with releasing it as a separate package is that you have to be careful with conflicts: ie A project needs `v0.1.1` and not `v0.1.0` while B project is the other way around. Thankfully, python `venv` can help with such cases.

Hope it helps

Comment: And if you're worried about uploading a 'useless' package to pypi you could alway just create a git repo with all your utility files and add that repo to your dependencies.

Comment: @urban Thanks, this is reassuring :) As for the last paragraph: Do you have a link that explains how to tell setuptools to install within a virtual environment, without forcing the end-user to create the virtual environment himself?

Comment: @Bananach `venv` will sort out the issue if you handle the conflicts/releases... If you have end users I am not 100% sure about the best approach. What I usually do in such cases is follow a `composer` (php) like approach - have an install.sh/Makefile that will download the dependencies in `<root>/vendor/` which is then included in the path... Python/setuptools might have an "official" way of doing this